# composer install not working and throwing error on custom attributes

Tags: magento2.4.5p1, composer-install

After git clone , i am running composer install to install magento, but throws following error

```
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                   
  The "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-custom-attribute-management/magento-module-custom-attribute-management-100.3.6.0.zi  
  p" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Version `100.4.4.0` works for me, you might want to try this version or up.

Execute this command:

```
composer require magento/module-custom-attribute-management:100.4.4.0
```

or try editing the version tag directly in your `composer.lock` file.

Happy coding!